# How to make infinity loop AnimatedPositioned?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is this any solution how easy repeat TweenAnimation or AnimatedPositioned? Suppose we want to make a flying ball back and forth in infinity loop.

How to do it most efficiently and cleanest?

Comment: you can read the next article: https://medium.com/@erdoganbavas/tween-animations-in-flutter-7e24844c1d19